# Issues calculating accuracy for custom BERT model

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm having some issues trying to calculate the accuracy of a custom BERT model which also uses the pretrained model from Huggingface. This is the code that I have :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics, linear_model
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from torch import cuda
import re
import torch.nn as nn

device = 'cuda' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
MAX_LEN = 200
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 8  # 12, 64
VALID_BATCH_SIZE = 4
EPOCHS = 1
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-4 #3e-4, 1e-4, 5e-5, 3e-5
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')
file1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
list_com = []
list_label = []
for line in file1:
 possible_labels = 'positive|negative'
 label = re.findall(possible_labels, line)
 line = re.sub(possible_labels, ' ', line)
 line = re.sub('\n', ' ', line)
 list_com.append(line)
 list_label.append(label[0])

list_tuples = list(zip(list_com, list_label))
file1.close()
labels = ['positive', 'negative']
df = pd.DataFrame(list_tuples, columns=['review', 'sentiment'])
df['sentiment'] = df['sentiment'].map({'positive': 1, 'negative': 0})
for i in range(0,len(df['sentiment'])):
 list_label[i] = df['sentiment'][i]
#print(df)

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
 def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer, max_len):
  self.tokenizer = tokenizer
  self.data = dataframe
  self.comment_text = dataframe.review
  self.targets = self.data.sentiment
  self.max_len = max_len
 def __len__(self):
  return len(self.comment_text)
 def __getitem__(self, index):
  comment_text = str(self.comment_text[index])
  comment_text = " ".join(comment_text.split())

  inputs = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(comment_text,None,add_special_tokens=True,max_length=self.max_len,
   pad_to_max_length=True,return_token_type_ids=False,truncation=True)
  ids = inputs['input_ids']
  mask = inputs['attention_mask']

  return {
   'ids': torch.tensor(ids, dtype=torch.long),
   'mask': torch.tensor(mask, dtype=torch.long),
   'targets': torch.tensor(self.targets[index], dtype=torch.float)
  }
train_size = 0.8
train_dataset=df.sample(frac=train_size,random_state=200)
test_dataset=df.drop(train_dataset.index).reset_index(drop=True)
train_dataset = train_dataset.reset_index(drop=True)

print("FULL Dataset: {}".format(df.shape))
print("TRAIN Dataset: {}".format(train_dataset.shape))
print("TEST Dataset: {}".format(test_dataset.shape))

training_set = CustomDataset(train_dataset, tokenizer, MAX_LEN)
testing_set = CustomDataset(test_dataset, tokenizer, MAX_LEN)
train_params = {'batch_size': TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,'shuffle': True,'num_workers': 0}
test_params = {'batch_size': VALID_BATCH_SIZE,'shuffle': True,'num_workers': 0}
training_loader = DataLoader(training_set, **train_params)
testing_loader = DataLoader(testing_set, **test_params)


class BERTClass(torch.nn.Module):
 def __init__(self):
   super(BERTClass, self).__init__()
   self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased',return_dict=False,num_labels = 2)
   self.lstm = nn.LSTM(768, 256, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
   self.linear = nn.Linear(256*2,2)

 def forward(self, ids , mask):
  sequence_output, pooled_output = self.bert(ids, attention_mask=mask )
  lstm_output, (h, c) = self.lstm(sequence_output)  ## extract the 1st token's embeddings
  hidden = torch.cat((lstm_output[:, -1, :256], lstm_output[:, 0, 256:]), dim=-1)
  linear_output = self.linear(lstm_output[:, -1].view(-1, 256 * 2))

  return linear_output

model = BERTClass()
model.to(device)
#print(model)
def loss_fn(outputs, targets):
 return torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(outputs, targets)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params =  model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

def train(epoch):
 model.train()
 for _, data in enumerate(training_loader, 0):
  ids = data['ids'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
  mask = data['mask'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
  targets = data['targets'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
  outputs = model(ids, mask)
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
  if _ % 1000 == 0:
   print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Loss:  {loss.item()}')
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  train(epoch)


def validation(epoch):
 model.eval()
 fin_targets = []
 fin_outputs = []
 with torch.no_grad():
  for _, data in enumerate(testing_loader, 0):
   ids = data['ids'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
   mask = data['mask'].to(device, dtype=torch.long)
   targets = data['targets'].to(device, dtype=torch.float)
   outputs = model(ids, mask)
   fin_targets.extend(targets.cpu().detach().numpy().tolist())
   fin_outputs.extend(torch.sigmoid(outputs).cpu().detach().numpy().tolist())
 return fin_outputs, fin_targets

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    outputs, targets = validation(epoch)
    outputs = np.array(outputs) >= 0.5
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(targets, outputs)
    print(f"Accuracy Score = {accuracy}")


torch.save(model.state_dict, 'model.pt')
print(f'Model saved!')
```

It should be a binary classification, positive(1) or negative(0), but when i try to compute the accuracy i get the error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and multilabel-indicator targets` oh this line `accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(targets, outputs)` .The outputs look like this:

```
[[ True False]
 [False False]
 [ True False]
 [ True False]
 [ True False]
 [ True False]
 [ True False]
 [False  True]
 [ True False]
 [ True False]
 [False  True]]
```

Can someone advise what would be the fix to this? Or if there something else that can improve this? Also, I saved the model and I want to know how can I use the saved model to classify user input in another .py file?(assuming that we enter a sentence from keyboard and we want the model to classify it).

Comment: Try changing num_labels to 1 (`it either is or isn't a dog`)

Comment: Tried that, i changed in this line `self.linear = nn.Linear(256*2,2)` (changed out_features to 1) but then i also have to change the loss function and i changed it into `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` but it prints [True] for all of them ...

Comment: Did you also try on this line `BertModel.from_pretrained` ?

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053295/valueerror-target-size-torch-size10-1-must-be-the-same-as-input-size-to?rq=1 and i changed out_features to 1 here nn.Linear(256*2,2) , changed the num_labels to 1(but i see i doesn't make any difference)  and changed the loss to this `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()`  and now it is able to compute the accuracy but the outputs is just [True] for all of them and thus the accuracy is low... It shouldn't print True for all of them though.. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please post the most recent version of your code? How is the loss during training? How long do you finetune. Just one epoch seems to be a bit short (better 2 or 3 because the lstm and linear head are untrained). I think also that your learning rate is a bit to high for finetuning. Better try 5e-5 or 2e-5 (which is recommend for Bert or finetuning purposes).